# HBase update operations on hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop2

Because HBase is based on HDFS, and that HDFS doesn't have update features, I was wondering if the update operations on it rewrites the whole HFILE files on hadoop?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no *updates* in HBase.

When you perform a delete in HBase (the whole row or particular cells), a special deletion marker is added to a cell. Upcoming scans or get operations would not see that cell(s).

When you perform an insert, you just create a new cell with current timestamp. Scan and get operations will return newer version of a cell.

Real physical deletion is perform during HBase [major compactions.](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/12/what-are-hbase-compactions/) Also, after compaction number of HFiles is reduced to provide faster read operations.